# Change localtime from UTC to UTC + 2 in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How I can change this code from localtime UTC to UTC+2. Now `hours()` function print 13 but I need to write 15.

```
import time;


def hours():
    localtime =  time.localtime(time.time())
    return localtime.tm_hour


def minutes():
    localtime =  time.localtime(time.time()) 
    return localtime.tm_min

def seconds():
   localtime =  time.localtime(time.time())     
   return localtime.tm_sec


print(hours())
    #minutes()
    #seconds()
```

Comment: Can't you add 2 to the return line:
return localtime.tm_hour+2

Comment: And when come 23 h I will see 25 :D

Comment: You can add 2 hours in seconds to time.time():
localtime =  time.localtime(time.time()+7200)
That won't cause that issue.

Comment: I am put like this but not work

def seconds():
   localtime = time.localtime(time.time()+7200)     
   return localtime.tm_sec

Comment: I'm probably not getting what you need, Timezone only refers to hours, you don't need to change it in the seconds or minutes as well anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using the datetime module:

```
import datetime;

today = datetime.datetime.now()
todayPlus2Hours = today + datetime.timedelta(hours=2)

print(todayPlus2Hours)

print(todayPlus2Hours.hour)
print(todayPlus2Hours.minute)
print(todayPlus2Hours.second)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use pytz along with datetime modules.
for a timezone reference i'd look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).
I'd do something of this sort:

```
import datetime
import pytz
utc_dt = datetime.datetime.now(tz=pytz.utc)
amsterdam_tz = pytz.timezone("Europe/Amsterdam")
local_amsterdam_time = amsterdam_tz.normalize(utc_dt)
print local_amsterdam_time.hour
print local_amsterdam_time.minute
print local_amsterdam_time.second
```

Comment: Do you know alternative with my code without import new library