# python: add timezone to time variable TUC to (UTC+2)

Tags: python, timezone

Im using docker to deploy. In my code

```
timestamp = "{:_%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S}".format(datetime.now())
```

When i printed date of the container used i found that is in UTC.
DOes anyone knows how to modify this row code to add the timezone please ?

Comment: Solution in following link may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32376750/change-localtime-from-utc-to-utc-2-in-python

Comment: @Shmn i saw the link thank you but normally this function **datetime.now()** did what im seeking for, i din't understand why im always in UTC

Comment: i was following this link https://julien.danjou.info/python-and-timezones/#:~:text=Python%20comes%20with%20a%20timestamp,time%2C%20one%20can%20use%20datetime. @Shamn please have a look. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are generating datetime object without any timezone info and so is assumed to be in UTC format

You need to pass in the needed timezone to `datetime.now()` call and adjust the format string to include timezone info

**Python >= 3.9**

From python 3.9 you have built-in support for timezones with `zoneinfo.ZoneInfo` class

```
>>> from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo
>>> tz = ZoneInfo("Europe/London")
>>> timestamp = "{:_%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S %Z}".format(datetime.now(tz))
>>> timestamp
'_2020_08_19_15_26_25 BST'
```

**Python < 3.9**

Install pytz (`pip install pytz`) for timezone support

```
>>> import pytz
>>> tz = pytz.timezone('Europe/London')
>>> timestamp = "{:_%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S %Z}".format(datetime.now(tz))
>>> timestamp
'_2020_08_18_13_44_22 BST'
```

Comment: Thank you for your response @Prem Anand :) its helpful. I can do either  **"{:_%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S}".format(datetime.now(tz=pytz.timezone('Europe/London')))** without adding **%Z** no ?

Comment: You need `%Z` to include the timezone info

Comment: But to have this result **_2020_08_18_13_44_22** don't need the **%Z** right. ?

Comment: If you dont include `%Z` it wont be immediately obvious what timezone the time is shown. If you are fine with that, you dont need to include `%Z`

Comment: thank you for your response, maybe im not clear,  im in egypt and running "{:_%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S}".format(datetime.now())  gives _2020_08_18_12_53_22 . What i want is to have simply _2020_08_18_14_53_22 .

Comment: to you see what i mean ??

Comment: notice that `pytz` is likely to be [deprecated](https://pypi.org/project/pytz-deprecation-shim/) with the release of Python 3.9

Comment: @MrFuppes. Thanks.. I have updated my answer for python3.9 using zoneinfo

Answer (score 0):

to get UTC now, simply use

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
timestamp = "{:_%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S}".format(datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc))
```

no need for an external library.